# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. when calling Stored Procedure from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, socketexception

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from my mysql database below is the code from my C# program and i keep getting the same error

> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly  respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has  failed to respond.

looking in the Database the Stored Procedure is working correctly, so is there a way of checking when the procedure is done
(First time asking a question on stack overflow I hope I provided enough info, if theres anything else let me know)

here's my C# code

```
 public void BasicCveInfoFill()
        {
            MySqlTransaction transaction = null;
            try
            {
                using(MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection= conn;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;                     
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = @"cveTableFill";                        
                        var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

the GetConnection method (switched to random database)

```
public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            string connString = @"server=localhost;user=root;database=test;password=";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            return conn;
        }
```

and this is the code of the stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cveTableFill;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE cveTableFill()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cpe INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  INSERT IGNORE INTO cve(cve_name, cpeMatchCount) SELECT c.cveMatch, COUNT(c.cveMatch) FROM cpe c GROUP BY c.cveMatch HAVING COUNT(c.cveMatch);
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

End;;
DELIMITER ;
```

this is the full exception

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
> (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.  --->
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error
> encountered attempting to read the resultset.  --->
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the
> stream has failed.  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data
> from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond..  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A
> connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
> respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond.    at
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
> Int64& insertedId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
> statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
> force)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
> VulnerabilityDB.SighburDatabaseConnect.BasicCveInfoFill() in
> C:\Dev\pcs\PcsProjects\SbomArenaC\VulnerabilityDB\SighburDatabaseConnect.cs:line
> 65

Comment: You have a connection issue, it is not even getting to the point of trying to run the procedure yet. Validate your GetConnection method is correct and using a valid connection string.

Comment: it actually is getting called the procedure executes immediately its the C# program program that's not getting notified that its done. thanks for responding though

Comment: What line of code throws the exception?

Comment: If it is not the database connection failing then it is something not shown, like a web API call or something.

Comment: var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  this is the error printing to the console "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

Comment: this method doesnt do anything besides whats shown it simply calls the stored procedure that inserts info from one table into another

Comment: @Crowcoder both the command and the connection are guarded with a using block. I may hope  the MySql dataprovider isn't so borked that it doesn't call close in its Dispose implementation? It has at least two chances to do that ....

Comment: What is the expected execution time of that stored procedure? What is the full exception stack? I can't imagine you only got a socket exception, lots of layers are involved between executing a command and have it blow-up. The other layers must leave a trace, at least have done an attempt to make sense of what happened.

Comment: @rene i edited the question with the full exception

Comment: @rene and the stored procedure executes in less then 10 seconds. way before any exceptions are thrown

Comment: Can you share  `GetConnection()`? Without any of the information concerning the user who accesses the system ofcourse :)

Comment: Is that Mysql server you connect to on your box or remote?

Comment: @Icepickle edited question with GetConnection method

Comment: @rene its local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the timeout from you command

cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

The command has a default timeout of 30 seconds

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout

> The time in seconds to wait for the command to execute. The default is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

check the connection state of your ole connection

```
myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed
```

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

The server ip address can be accessed by client.  The server may not be listening on the port

Quote:
Check that the hostname/port is correct, server is online, firewall isn't dropping packets etc.

Error
Connection timed out.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: i ran it already with taking out transaction, it doesn't make a difference